# How to create Gradle build for existing IDEA project?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Groovy project in Intellij IDEA 13.1.5 that I want to build with Gradle. So I have installed Gradle itself and enabled the Gradle plugin in IDEA.

But how can I now build the project (or better: start to write the Gradle build file) from within IDEA? I have created a `build.gradle` file in the project's module, which is recognized by IDEA correctly as Gradle file, according to the icon next to the file name.

Beside that I don't know how to continue from there. IDEA documentation says I should open the Gradle Tools window, but I can find it in View --> Tool Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745541/best-way-to-add-gradle-support-to-intellij-project help with your question?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to accomplish this while still being in the same directory is by going to `File -> New -> Module From Existing Sources..` and then selecting your `build.gradle`.

Comment: This works - I have tried it. BTW, the answer of @PeterNiederweiser does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Gradle Run configuration. To get all IntelliJ Gradle features, you need to import the project via Gradle (`File->Import Project`, then point it to `build.gradle`).

Comment: I think this is not what I really need. That way a new project is created in IDEA. But I want to add Gradle support to an **existing** IDEA project.

Comment: As I said, you should be able to create a Gradle Run configuration even for an existing project, but you'll need to create a new project to use most other features (because they require a project that's synced with the Gradle build). Typically you should also see a "link to Gradle build" popup; I don't know if that's effectively different from recreating the project.

Comment: I was hoping to somehow get all Gradle features even for an existing IDEA project...