# Best way to add Gradle support to IntelliJ Project

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gradle

I have looked around quite a bit and haven't found the best solution to convert an existing IntelliJ project to Gradle. I work in a team environment and we currently share the .ipr file as we have a few build configurations that we track. We will be getting rid of those in favor of Gradle eventually but I can't screw things up too much until the Gradle conversion is done.

Also, our Java source files are located in the root of the src directory instead of src/main/java as is standard.

Is there a way I can add Gradle to my project that won't make me delete and recreate my IntelliJ project and won't screw everyone else up when they do a Git pull?

Comment: To answer the question of your source directory - you need to override the default source directory with [sourceSets](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html).  See how we did this in the MongoDB Java driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/782a8c58cf13b0026ed4d58bfd6b74f1248c4b08/build.gradle#L110

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Add:

```
build.gradle
```

in your root project folder, and use plugin for example:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
//and standard one
apply plugin: 'java'
```

and with this fire from command line:

```
gradle cleanIdea
```

and after that:

```
gradle idea
```

After that everything should work

Comment: when attempting this solution did anyone come across the error "Module 'xx' is not backed by gradle? if so how was it resolved

Comment: Thanks this was driving me crazy and I couldn't figure out how to make IntelliJ refresh the projects dependencies after adding it to build.gradle.

Comment: gradle idea (that depends on ideaProject, ideaModule, ideaWorkspace) did not work for me as ideaModule kept failing. Instead, the task gradle ideaProject worked fine and the project is now Gradle-enabled.

Comment: Alright there is a problem with this approach. You'll get a "dependencies cannot be applied to groovy.lang.closure" error. Check out this solution instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168175/2517730

Comment: This is somewhat outdated, since the idea Gradle plugin still resorts to the file-based idea project, while the folder-based project is standard and much more handy

Comment: well I don't have global local gradle on my system, usually it downloads specific gradle version for every project separately **gradle: command not found**...

Comment: Better instructions would be helpful. What does "use plugin for example" mean? Am I supposed to type those commands somewhere? Also, "gradle cleanIdea" just gives me an error: Task 'cleanIdea' not found in root project 'HamsterBall'.

Answer (score 76):

There is no need to remove any `.iml` files. Follow this:

- close the project
- `File` `->` `Open...` and choose your newly created `build.gradle`
- IntelliJ will ask you whether you want:

  - `Open Existing Project`
  - **`Delete Existing Project and Import`**
- Choose the second option and you are done

Comment: How can i fix the problem, that the new project has to be in another folder?

Comment: Does this add the JARs from your Project Structure | Libraries as dependencies and the create an EAR (using the plugin)  as defined the in Project Structure | Artifacts?

Comment: @NOTiFY I doubt it does. It's equivalent to checking out project from scratch.

Comment: @Michal Kordas I added all the dependencies by hand, didn't take anywhere near the time i expected and now add the WAR, JAR & EAR creation. There's a feature request for this at JetBrains https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6990

Answer (score 50):

Another way, simpler.

Add your

```
build.gradle
```

file to the root of your project. Close the project. Manually remove "*.iml" file and/or ".idea" directory. Then choose "Import Project...", navigate to your project directory, select the *build.gradle* file and click OK.

Answer (score 22):

In IntelliJ 2017.2.4 I just closed the project and reopened it and I got a dialog asking me if I wanted to link with *build.gradle* which opened up the import dialog for Gradle projects.

No need to delete any files or add the *idea* plugin to *build.gradle*.

Comment: Can confirm this works nicely. Just run gradle init in the project root, then you'll get the dialog next time you open the project.

Answer (score 17):

Just as a future reference, if you already have a `Maven` project all you need to do is doing a `gradle init` in your project directory which will generates `build.gradle` and other dependencies, then do a `gradle build` in the same directory.

Comment: Of interest: [Creating New Gradle Builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/) - Notes: `gradle init` can generate various different types of projects, and even knows how to translate simple `pom.xml` files to Gradle.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Version 12 of IntelliJ.

I solved a similar problem by creating an entirely new project and "Checking out from Version Control"
Merging the two projects later was fairly easy.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add `build.gradle` in your project's root directory.
2. Then just `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Here is a basic build.gradle for Java projects:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'
version = '1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers. For me it was helpful to delete `.mvn` directory and then add `build.gradle`. New versions of IntelliJ will then automatically notice that you use Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Open the context menu by clicking on **gradle.build** file and then press "**Link Gradle project**" (or something like that - I have just done it and the menu is not available anymore in my project, because my project is now linked as a Gradle project). Then you will have Gradle tab at the right window of your Intellij Idea.