# Convert Java Project to Gradle Project in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a very basic java project.

In Eclipse there is an option to convert a project to a maven project all you have to do is right click on the java project and click **"Convert to Maven Project"**. So basically it creates a pom.xml file for you.

Does IntelliJ have a similar command to convert to Gradle? Searched around but it did not seem like it does.

Comment: The below link should help you.first convert the java project to build using gradle in eclipse then you can import that in Intellij.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615872/configuring-existing-eclipse-java-project-to-build-using-gradle

Comment: "Add Framework Support" is the menu option

Comment: How to update IntelliJ to recognize when the repo was converted from Maven to Gradle?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The simple way to migrate from Maven to Gradle via Intellij IDEA is:

1. Install Gradle Build Tool from https://gradle.org/
2. Add Path to System Enviroments (like in Gradle instructions)
3. Open your Maven project in Intellij IDEA and then open "Terminal" tab.
4. Write `gradle init`.  Wait until the building process ends and then save & close your project.
5. Reopen your project and click *Auto-import*, and wait while Gradle is running.  Approximate time - 5 mins.

Comment: I reopened my project as step 5. but no auto-import pop up came up. could you please help me with that?

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  The OP is not trying to convert from Maven to Gradle, they're trying to convert from an IntelliJ project to Gradle.  That's different.

Comment: Hi) The same worked for intellij (without maven). Just open Terminal and do other steps. Worked for me

Comment: This did nothing useful, it just created a default build.gradle file that doesn't contain any of the settings from my IntelliJ .iml files.

Comment: @JesseBarnum it converts pop.xml to gradle not iml to gradle.

Answer (score 5):

**Convert a regular project into a Gradle project**﻿

1. Open your project in IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Create a build.gradle file. Add the information you need.

example:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
}
```

As soon as you create a build.gradle file, IntelliJ IDEA recognizes the Gradle build script and displays a notification suggesting to load the project as Gradle. After you load the project, IntelliJ IDEA enables the Gradle tool window.

From: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#convert_project_to_gradle

Answer (score 2):

- Close your project (you may want to commit first)
- Select "New Project"
- Select Gradle (and any other frameworks you need)
- Enter the directory where the Idea project to be converted is and
  click "Finish"

Idea should handle the rest, you may need to move your files into main/java (etc)

I don't think there's a simple way to do this in place.