# IntelliJ plugin: maven, gradle and travis-ci

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cradle

Currently, my built structure for a plugin in is a bit messy: I'm using the normal IDEA project file to build the plugin locally. When I push it to the repo and travis-ci is building it, it uses the maven [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-IntelliJ-Plugin/blob/develop/pom.xml) because for travis to work, it always has to download the complete IDEA sources.

Although this works, this has several drawbacks:

1. I need to keep two built mechanisms up to date. This is

   - When a new IDEA version is out (every few weeks), I need to change the SDK in maven and in my IDEA settings
   - When I add a new library, change resources, etc. I need to do this for two the two settings as well
2. I ran into problems when I kept the IDEA Maven plugin turned on because it saw the `pom.xml` and interfered with my local built. Turning it off means, I cannot download libraries with Maven which has the feature of tracking dependencies.

I saw that Gradle has an 'idea' plugin and after googling, I got the impression that Gradle is the preferred choice these days. I have seen [Best way to add Gradle support to IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26745541/1078614) and I'm sure I can use the answers there to turn my `pom.xml` into a valid `build.gradle`.

However, maybe someone else has already done this or can provide a better approach. What I'm looking for is a unified way to build my plugin locally and on Travis-CI.

### Some Details

For compiling an IDEA plugin, you need its SDK which you can access through an installation of IDEA or a download of the complete package. Locally, I'm using my installation for the SDK. With Travis, my maven built has the rule to download the `tar.gz` and extract it.

Comment: Gradle is a poor choice. Why anyone seems to like it is beyond me. You haven't explained what the underlying problem is beyond saying that it interferes with your local build. If you explain the real problem we might be able to save you all the time and effort you'd have spent failing to progress with gradle.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Sorry for the long delay. The real reason for touching this is that I wanted to use a library for accessing the GitHub API. When I use the full jar containing all dependencies, then I run into trouble because one of the libs is already provided. So I wanted to use Maven to get the pure GitHub jar and let it resolve missing dependencies which did not work as now pointed out in my edited question.

Comment: Are you aware of dependency exclusion? https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in particular for building an IntelliJ plugin, Gradle seems to have many advantages. This is mainly due to the great IntelliJ plugin for Gradle which makes compiling plugins so much easier. With Gradle, I could turn my >220 lines of Maven build into a few lines of easily readable Gradle code. The main advantages are that

1. It takes care of downloading and using the correct IDEA SDK while you only have to specify the IDEA version.
2. It can publish your plugin to your Jetbrains repository and make it instantly available to all users
3. It fixes items in your `plugin.xml`, e.g. you can use one central version number in `gradle.build` and it will keep `plugin.xml` up-to-date or it can include change-notes
4. It seamlessly integrates with Travis-CI

### How to use Gradle with an existing IDEA plugin

Do it manually. It's much easier.

1. Create an empty `build.gradle` file
2. Look at an [example](https://github.com/halirutan/IntelliJ-Key-Promoter/blob/KeyPromoterX/build.gradle) and read through the [README](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) (there are many `build.gradle` of projects at the end) to see what each intellij property does.
3. Adapt it to your plugin by

   1. Setting the `intellij.version` you want to build against
   2. Setting your `intellij.pluginName`
   3. Define where your sources and resources are
   4. Define your [plugin version](https://github.com/halirutan/IntelliJ-Key-Promoter/blob/KeyPromoterX/build.gradle#L38)
   5. Define a [Gradle wrapper](https://github.com/halirutan/IntelliJ-Key-Promoter/blob/KeyPromoterX/build.gradle#L34) that enables people (and Travis) to build your plugin without having Gradle
4. Create the gradle wrapper scripts with `gradle wrapper`
5. Test and fix your build process locally with `./gradlew assemble`

If everything works well, you can push `build.gradle`, `gradlew`, `gradlew.bat` and the `gradle`-folder to your repo.

### Building with Travis-CI

For Travis you want to use the `gradlew` script for building. To do so, you need to make it executable in the travis run. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/halirutan/IntelliJ-Key-Promoter/blob/KeyPromoterX/.travis.yml).