# How to use Gradle for an existing Java project?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I just started learning how to use gradle. I want to make a jar associated with an existing project,but i really can't figure out how to "stick" my existing Java project to a new Gradle project in **IntelliJ**.

I made a new Gradle project and i have the src package. I suppose that i have to put there my existing project. But how? When i tried to import an existing project,it asks me for gradle.build file which of course,doesn't exist in my Java project.

How i can "stick" my Java projects to a new Gradle Project?

Comment: Make new project... Copy files into src/main/java not use the "import" menu

Comment: Tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745541/best-way-to-add-gradle-support-to-intellij-project?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can create a gradle.build file which should be used instead of pom.xml if you're using maven. The concept it's similar with maven, from plane are just few differences. One of them it's the fact that gradle uses Groovy as language, instead of xml file definitions from maven. You don't need to create another project and copy the sources there. Here it'a step-by-step tutorial for you need: https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/

Comment: This assumes that the project was using Maven at all, no?

Comment: Yeah, all I said it's possible only if your old project was a maven one.