# Adding Krangl SDK to IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am new to `Kotlin` and `IntelliJ Idea IDE`.

I want to experiment with `Krangl`. But how do I add that SDK to my `IntelliJ Idea IDE`. In `C#` there is `Nuget` and on Mac `cocoapods`.
I know this is a very noob question, but I cannot find a solution that is apparent to me. I am C#/.NET/MS developer looking to get my feet wet in this new world.
There is no `Gradle` in the `IntelliJ Idea IDE` as far as I can see. Just `Maven` and `Ant`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure there is Gradle in IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-gradle.html

So, you can either use Gradle or Maven. Or you could also add the jar as a dependency to your project, but I won't recommend this.

Comment: wait I have a project how can i add gradle to it? or am i supposed to create a sister gradle project for it?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745541/best-way-to-add-gradle-support-to-intellij-project

Comment: i tried to do a new project just to see and got this error not my day :)
Error adding module to project: Sorry but parent: com.intellij.ide.util.newProjectWizard.AddSupportForFrameworksPanel@57bf304 has already been disposed (see the cause for stacktrace) so the child: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.configuration.KotlinGradleFrameworkSupportInModuleConfigurable@e9bb98e will never be disposed